# Recursively removing elements from a list in Racket

Tags: racket

I need to deep remove an element from a list in Racket. This means that in any sublist, I need the element to also be removed from there as well. I'm getting an error message I quite don't understand. Here is my code:

```
(define (my_delete atm lst);define function and set up parameters
  (define (rm x ls);define remove function
    (if (null? ls);check to see whether the list is null
      '();return a null list
      (if (eqv? x (car ls));check to see whether x is equal to the current element in the list
          (rm x (cdr ls));recursively call the function
          (cons (car ls)
                (rm x (cdr ls))))));recursively call the function
  (define (my-map f lst2);define my-map function and set up parameters
  (cond
   [(empty? lst2) empty];if the list is empty return an empty list
   [else (cons (f (first lst2) lst);apply the mapAction function to the element
               (my-map f (rest lst2)))]));recursively call the function
  (define (mapAction atm2 lst2);define mapAction function and set up parameters
    (if (list? atm2));check to see whether the element is a list
        (my_delete atm atm2);recursively call the function
        (if (eq? atm atm2));check to see whether the elements are equal
        (rm atm2 lst2);remove the element if they are equal
    
  )
  (my-map mapAction list)
)
```

And here is my error message:

```
if: bad syntax in: (if (list? atm2))
```

Please do help!

Comment: The number of arguments in `if` is wrong. See the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder what `(if (list? atm2))` is supposed to do when `(list? atm2)` is either true or false. Usually you would have `(if (list? atm2) expression-if-true expreession-if-false)`. Also in DrRacket when I pres CTRL+i it formats the code according to these parentheses errors. I'll annotate `mapAction` for you:

```
(define (mapAction atm2 lst2) ; define mapAction function and set up parameters
  (if (list? atm2))           ; check to see whether the element is a list don't do ANYTHING either way
  (my_delete atm atm2)        ; Then always recursively call the function 
  (if (eq? atm atm2))         ; Then ignore the result and check to see whether the elements are equal and dont do ANYTHING wither way
  (rm atm2 lst2))             ; Than always remove the element unconditionally (also result of procedure)
```

This is something completely different:

```
(define (mapAction atm2 lst2) ; define mapAction function and set up parameters
  (if (list? atm2)            ; check to see whether the element is a list
      (my_delete atm atm2)    ; recursively call the function
      (if (eq? atm atm2)      ; check to see whether the elements are equal
          (rm atm2 lst2)      ; remove the element if they are equal
          'what-to-do-else))) ; if has 3 parts. THis is executed when atm and atm2 are not the same thing
```

This would look better with `cond` since it has nested terms in the else branch, as in if elseif else.